# Understanding Sparse Data Structures in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having to handle dataframes that are bigger than the RAM on my local machine. I'm therefore looking at using sparse data structures.

The need initially came about when creating dummy variables and from the manual, I noticed that pd.get_dummies() has a `sparse = True` option and so I used that on a test sample and got expected behaviour:

```
>>> test=pd.get_dummies(df, sparse=True)
>>> testSparsed = test.to_sparse()
>>> testDensed = test.to_dense()

>>> test.memory_usage().sum()
# expect no change as already sparse
>>> testSparsed.memory_usage().sum() 
# expect change on conversion to dense
>>> testDensed.memory_usage().sum()

89652
89652
25789582
```

However, as an experiment, I tried to convert a 'normal' df to a sparse df after the creation of dummies and here is where I got unexpected behaviour:

```
>>> test2=pd.get_dummies(df, sparse=False)
>>> test2Sparsed = test2.to_sparse()
>>> test2Densed = test2.to_dense()

>>> test2.memory_usage().sum()
# expect change on sparse conversion
>>> test2Sparsed.memory_usage().sum() 
# expect same as test2
>>> test2Densed.memory_usage().sum() 

25789582
25789582
25789582
```

It is my expectation that `test2Sparsed.memory_usage().sum()` should be smaller than the other values but it isn't.

I've searched on Stack Overflow and haven't found any relevant answers.

When pickling these objects and looking at the file size on the command line, I get the following

```
> ls -sh test testSparsed testDensed test2 test2Sparsed test2Densed
2992 test    2992 testSparsed       50856 testDensed     50864 test2         
53344 test2Sparsed   50864 test2Densed
```

checking the types of the test2 dataframes suggests that the memory should be smaller for test2Sparsed:

```
>>> type(test2)
>>> type(test2Sparsed)
>>> type(test2Densed)

pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
pandas.core.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

So my question is, why is calling `.to_sparse()` on a dense dataframe not appearing to change the size of it?

Comment: Sparse data structures work only if the data you're working on is sparse itself. Pandas keeps everything in memory, so if it doesn't fit (and it's not sparse) then there's nothing you can do, but switching to another library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see in the [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sparse.html) documentation. You have to specify the value to omit in the representation with `fill_value`. By default `fill_value = None`.

```
DataFrame.to_sparse(fill_value=None, kind='block')
```

When you are using `test = pd.get_dummies(df, sparse=True)`, the values of the DataFrame `test` are equal to a [SparseArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.SparseArray.html#pandas.SparseArray). You can see that the values by default for `fill_value` depend on the type of the data.

```
data.dtype  na_value
float   np.nan
int 0
bool    False
datetime64  pd.NaT
timedelta64 pd.NaT
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! Using `pd.get_dummies()` with `sparse=false` returns a dataframe consisting of ones and zeros and therefore the default of `to_sparse()` being `None` was causing no reduction in size.